# get iframe inside div with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a way to do the following in JavaScript?

1. get a div by a class name,
2. get the iframe inside the div
3. and add an attribute (frameborder = 0)

---

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="calendar">
            <iframe></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get a div by class name:

```
var allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("calendar");
```

Assuming there's only one

```
var calendarDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("calendar")[0];
```

Get the iFrame inside:

```
var iFrame = calendarDiv.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
```

set an attribute:

```
iFrame.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
```

---

Or, since `getElementsByClassName` isn't supported in old versions of IE, consider setting the id on the `iFrame` and simply doing:

```
document.getElementById("iFrameId").setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
```

Comment: Note that `document.getElementsByClassName` isn't supported in ie8 and lower: http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName

Comment: NOTE: `document.getElementsByClassname()` [doesn't work in IE under version 9](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements). Check out [alternatives](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/your_favourite_1) and how to use them [gracefully](http://www.ehow.com/how_7398289_use-implemented-two-different-browsers.html).

Comment: @AymanSafadi - thank you - I edited to notify OP of that.  I hate IE.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to give your iframe id.

After that, you can get your iframe with the function document.getElementById(""), and than to change it's property.

For example:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="calendar">
        <iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("myIframe").frameborder = 1;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```